# Terminology for free variables

Tags: logic, terminology, quantifiers, sequent-calculus

Suppose you have a proof along the lines of

$$\begin{array} {rc}
\text{Assume:} & x > 2 \\
& \vdots \\
& \text{Some logic stuff} \\
& \vdots \\
\text{Conclude:} & x > 1 \\
\end{array}$$

Two common ways for this to be interpreted are ***(1)*** $(\forall x~.~x > 2) \to (\forall x~.~x > 1)$ and ***(2)*** $\forall x~.~(x > 2 \to x > 1)$. Logics that intend the first way include PRA and Hilbert style FOL.  Logics that intend the second way include Fitch style Natural Deduction.

Is there common terminology to distinguish the two approaches to interpreting how the free variables are shared between propositions in a proof?  Or if you have reason to think there are no such common terms, what would you suggest?

Comment: There is a termonolgu used by Kleene into his [Intro to metamath (1952)](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ), page 95 : a variable is *varied* in a given deduction vs *held costant*. Absolutely **not** "standard"...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for that reference.  I'm also interested in recommendations if you have any.

Comment: Maybe something like [global vs local](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/55ac76c776b8fea47a000184) ? In your first example the free var $x$ is implicitly universally quantified "locally", i.e. in the context of the single assumption, while in case (2) above it is quantified "globally", i.e. in the context of the entire derivation.

Comment: Interesting, I was actually thinking the exact same thing.  Thanks~